# Reduced decomposition of an element in the Weyl group smaller length than it should have

Tags: lie-algebras, algebraic-groups, root-systems, reductive-groups, weyl-group

I am making some mistake computing an example with root systems, but I have so far been unable to find it.  Let $J$ be the $6$ by $6$ matrix with $1$s on the antidiagonal, and take $G = \textrm{SO}_6(\mathbb{C})$ as those $g \in \textrm{SL}_6(\mathbb{C})$ for which $^tg Jg = J$.

The standard maximal torus $T$ for $G$ is the elements of the form $\textrm{diag}(t_1,t_2,t_3,t_3^{-1},t_2^{-1},t_1^{-1})$.  If $e_1, e_2, e_3$ is the standard basis for $X(T)$, then a system of positive roots of $T$ in $G$ is

$$\Phi^+ = \{e_1 - e_2, e_1 - e_3, e_1 + e_3,e_1 + e_2, e_2 - e_3, e_2 + e_3\}$$

for which the base is $\alpha_1 = e_1-e_2, \alpha_2 = e_2 - e_3, \alpha_3 =  e_2 + e_3$.  The Weyl group $W = N_G(T)/T$ can be identified with the group of signed permutations of $1, 2, 3$ where you are allowed to change exactly two signs at a time.  Let $s_i$ be the simple reflection corresponding to $\alpha_i$.  Then $s_1 = (1 \, 2), s_2 = (2 \, 3)$, and $s_3$ swaps $2$ and $-2$, as well as $3$ and $-3$.

Consider the Weyl group element

$$w_0 = s_1s_3s_1 \in W$$

It swaps $1$ and $-1$, and swaps $3$ and $-3$, and leaves $2$ and $-2$ alone.  The length of $w_0$ should be the number of positive roots it makes negative.  It seems like it makes four positive roots negative: $e_1 - e_2, e_1 - e_3, e_1 +e_3,$ and $e_1 + e_2$.  Yet its length above is $\leq 3$.  How can this be?

Comment: You computed $s_3$ false, I guess. Correctly, it must say $s_3$ maps $1$ to $1$, $2$ to $-3$ and $3$ to $-2$. Then you find that the inversion set of $w=s_1s_3s_1$ consists of the elements $\alpha_1,\alpha_3$ and $\alpha_1+\alpha_3$. So, the inversion set of $w$ has three elements. On the other hand, three is also the length of $w$, namely the number of simple reflections in the reduced expression $s_1s_3s_1$.

Comment: Thank you, you're right.  I just checked that $s_3$ can be represented modulo $T$ by the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ & & & 1 \\ & & & & 1 \\ & 1 \\ & & 1 \\ & & & & & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$ which does send $e_2$ to $-e_3$ and $e_3$ to $-e_2$.